# NodeJs test case for code in side forEach method of array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

here files is a array like var files = ['/tmp/1.pdf', '/tmp/2.pdf'];

Method:

```
var createAttachmentsForMail = function (files) {
    var attachmets = [];

    files.forEach(function (value) {
        attachmets.push(
            {
                "Content-type": mime.lookup(value),
                "FileName": path.basename(value),
                "content": new   Buffer(fs.readFileSync(value)).toString('base64')
            }
        );
    });

    return attachmets;
};
```

Test method: **I want to test that attachment.push is called 2 times but how? I also want to assert what attachments are return.**

```
describe("Create attachments", function() {

    it('from pdf path', function() {

        var files = [
            '/tmp/1.pdf',
            '/tmp/2.pdf'
        ];

        sinon.stub(fs, "readFileSync");

        sinon.stub(files);

        mailSender.createAttachmentsForMail(files);

        sinon.assert.calledOnce(files.forEach);

        fs.readFileSync.restore();
        files.forEach.restore();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just check that the return value from createAttachmentsForMail is an array of those two items?

Comment: @AndersBornholm ok can please you write code to write just check return value from createAttachmentsForMail? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `sinon.stub(files);` you stab all the methods of files array. This means that forEach won't actually be executed and you will not produce any files.
That is why I guess you could not check the number of files.

Second thing is that there is no need to test things like 'if .push was called twice' or 'if .forEach' was called. Becuase if you slightly change the implementation (for example you started using lodash _.each instead of Array.prototype.forEach) your tests will stop working.

You should test behavior, not the internal implementation.

```js
var assert = require('assert');

describe('#createAttachmentsForMail', () => {
 it('should form proper file names/content types etc', function() {

  var files = [
   '/tmp/1.pdf',
   '/tmp/2.pdf'
  ];

  //Also let's make readFileSync always return mocked data
  sinon.stub(fs, "readFileSync", () => 'mocked content');

  var attachments = createAttachmentsForMail(files);
  //Test that we received 2 attachments.
  assert.equal(attachments.length, 2);

  for (var attachment of attachments) {
   //Check if we received a proper content type
   assert.equal(attachment['Content-type'], 'application/pdf');
   //Do other needed checks ...
  }
  
  fs.readFileSync.restore();
 });
});
```

I used 'assert' module just for simplicity. I'd suggest '[chai](http://chaijs.com/)' as a more robust assert library.